# Block-based animation with animated images

Tags: objective-c, animation, xcode4, uiimageview

I have been trying create simple "block-based animation". I am using an array of images "images" here. I used this method:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 
                       delay:0.0f 
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
                  animations:^{ imageview.animationImages = images; } 
                  completion:nil];
```

However no change happens when I alter the values of parameters `animateWithDuration:` and `delay:` I want to slow down the animation but no change happens even when I change these values to 20-30. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

To change images in a `UIImageView`, you don't have to put it inside an animation block. You have to use `UIImageView`'s `animationImages` and `animationDuration` properties, as well as probably `- startAnimating` and `- stopAnimating` methods of the `UIImageView`.

Comment: allright i can try that but how am i gonna deal with delay? I want my animation to start after 1 second delay. Thx.

Comment: You could do have `[imageView performSelector:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]` in the `- viewWillAppear` method.

Answer (score 0):

Add array of images to

> animationImages

of UIImageView

> and give some animationDuration